# trying to display data using SPARQL

Tags: sparql

so I am trying to display top 10 richest tennis players. I want to make a query that lists tennis players according to their name ,net worth ,and nationality.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?networths ?nationality WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item (COUNT(?statement2) AS ?networths) (COUNT(?statement1) AS ?nationality) WHERE {
      ?item p:P106 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P106/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q10833314.
      ?item p:P27 ?statement1.
      ?statement1 (ps:P27/(wdt:P279*)) _:anyValueP27.
      ?item p:P2218 ?statement2.
      ?statement2 (psv:P2218/wikibase:quantityAmount) ?numericQuantity.
    }
  GROUP BY ?item ORDER BY DESC (?networths) 
  }
}
ORDER BY DESC (?networths)
```

Comment: why would you `count` the nationality as well as the net worth? I mean, count is counting how many of those values exists, but that won't give you the value itself.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?networths ?nationality ?nationalityLabel  {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?networths ?nationality  {
      ?item p:P106/ps:P106/wdt:P279* wd:Q10833314.
      ?item p:P27/ps:P27 ?nationality .
      ?item p:P2218/(psv:P2218/wikibase:quantityAmount) ?networths.
    }
  ORDER BY DESC (?networths) 
  }
}
ORDER BY DESC (?networths)` - but obviously, the net worth doesn't exist for many players, e.g. check [Rafael Nadal](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q10132)

Comment: I know that net worth docent exist for many players but the top 10 richest players should be visible

Comment: your solution repeats names why

Comment: it mostly shows the two nationalities of a player separately

Comment: why do you expect the 10 richest players? I even gave you a counter example by one of the most prominent and successful tennis plays in the world